# Submit appeal to App Store after my app was rejected

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have submitted my app to App Store with demo account credentials. Unfortunately they entered the wrong credentials, rejected my app and sent a screen shot also.
But I can see in the screen shot that they entered the wrong password instead of the submitted password in the demo account.
I sent a reply to apple through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal)

Now my question is: do I have to submit same binary and same demo account again, or should I keep it like that and wait for their reply?

thanks

Comment: Please Share Screen shot of Apple review.

Comment: [link](http://a1798.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple18/v4/ae/55/0e/ae550e82-26d8-b94f-fa4a-e013b23f99db/temp..nwaxvehj.png?downloadKey3=1469272512_6e8f0d77c8c9fbb786db2323f8efe352)

Comment: Apple review ? What Apple says ? It was just screenshot of your app. give us detail Info about what apple says.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store support, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: Information Needed


We were unable to sign in to review your app with the provided demo account. 

We've attached a screenshot of the error message displayed when we attempted to sign in.

Please provide valid demo account details in the App Review Information section for your app in iTunes Connect. Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.

Comment: Whenever you are giving a build to apple please make sure that the account Info is right or wrong. As I gone through the apple review the account information you gave is wrong.

Comment: @SagarShirbhate I am asking the same. The account information I have given is right but they entered wrong

Comment: no not possible whatever you have been mentioned to use demo account they use exact same. We cant make them fool.

Comment: And In the Screen shot Password have secure text Like *** how you know that they entered wrong password ?

Comment: I can count number of characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change the demo account username and password (please double check your demo account credential). And regarding the binary, yes, you have to resubmit a new binary for this type of rejection.

Note :- when you see **Binary Rejected**, then you have to resubmit a new binary after changing the **build number**.

[image]

**Edit :-** You can use **Reply** option below the issue section to reply to them. They will give you detailed explanation regarding your app rejection on the second day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will have to mark issue reported by apple as resolved and again submit the same binary which is already present in your account.