# iOS app is rejected as "Spam"

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have similar apps with different design & color theme as per my different client. But apple is now rejected my latest app as **spam**

**Apple message**

> Guideline 4.3 - Design - Spam
>
> We noticed that your app provides the same feature set as other apps
>   you've submitted to the App Store; it simply varies in content or
>   language, which is considered a form of spam.
>
> Next Steps
>
> When creating multiple apps where content is the only varying element,
>   you should offer a single app to deliver differing content to
>   customers. Alternatively, you may consider creating a web app, which
>   looks and behaves similar to a native app when the customer adds it to
>   their Home screen. Refer to the Configuring Web Applications section
>   of the Safari Web Content Guide for more information.
>
> You will experience a delayed review process if you deliberately
>   disregard the App Store Review Guidelines, ignore previous rejection
>   feedback in future app submissions, or use your app to mislead or
>   deceive users.
>
> Important Information
>
> As a result of violating this guideline, your app’s review has been
>   delayed. Future submissions of this app, and other apps associated
>   with your Apple Developer account, will also experience a delayed
>   review. Deliberate disregard of the App Store Review Guidelines and
>   attempts to deceive users or undermine the review process are
>   unacceptable and is a direct violation Section 3.2(f) of the Apple
>   Developer Program License Agreement. Continuing to violate the Terms &
>   Conditions of the Apple Developer Program will result in the
>   termination of your account, as well as any related or linked
>   accounts, and the removal of all your associated apps from the App
>   Store.
>
> We want to provide a safe experience for users to get apps and a fair
>   environment for all developers to be successful. If you believe we
>   have misunderstood or misinterpreted the intent of your app, you may
>   submit an appeal for consideration or provide additional clarification
>   by responding directly to this message in Resolution Center in iTunes
>   Connect.
>
> For app design information, check out the following videos: "Best
>   Practices for Great iOS UI Design" and "Designing Intuitive User
>   Experiences," available on the Apple Developer website.
>
> You may also want to review the iOS Human Interface Guidelines for
>   more information on how to create a great user experience in your app.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about AppStore app submission belong to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about app design / Apple App Store app review policies instead of directly about programming or coding.

Comment: What is the context? Do you have 3 apps or 300 apps - this seems like a routine customer support request without any of the data needed to even guide you past a “get with your team and figure out what the store rules are” type of suggestion. .

Answer (score 3):

They are explaining a possible solution in section "`Next Steps`". Apple has taken a stance against clones in the past but even more so after introducing guideline `4.2.6 - Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected.` this year.

You have two/three possible solutions:

- Change the design of your app so it doesn't look the same as your other apps
- *Appeal the rejection or provide additional clarification*

Comment: How to do a appeal for this. My app is developed using Xcode IDE but it Is rejected by iTunes with 4.2.6 - Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495408/submit-appeal-to-app-store-after-my-app-was-rejected. This is off-topic in SO, try asking in https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or Apple's Dev Forums